# Como ordenar un SELECT para que dos datos iguales no sean consecutivos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Al momento de crear el procedure para listar ciertos datos necesito ordenarlos para que los datos de la row no sean iguales, por ejemplo, tengo este procedure el cual funciona como un filtro:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FILTRO_JUV_68_MAS_K_EL()
BEGIN
    SELECT NOMBRE_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT FROM ATLETA WHERE ANO_NAC_AT <= 2007 AND ANO_NAC_AT >= 2005 AND CAT_PESO_AT = '-68' AND SEXO_AT = 'M' AND CATEGORIA_AT = 'K' AND CINT_CAT_AT = 'ELITE';
END//
```

Ahora mismo el procedure funciona de manera correcta porque el output es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si en algún momento varios atletas se inscriben al mismo tiempo y el registro es continuo entonces va a aparecer algo similar a esto:

```
|NOMBRE_AT        |NOM_ACADEMIA_AT
|-----------------|---------------
|IVAN COTO        |In Neh Kwan
|RICARDO JIMENEZ  |In Neh Kwan
|THIAGO FERNANDEZ |YIN YANG
```

Por lo que me gustaría que si ese es el caso entonces se ordene de la siguiente forma:

```
|NOMBRE_AT        |NOM_ACADEMIA_AT
|-----------------|---------------
|IVAN COTO        |In Neh Kwan
|THIAGO FERNANDEZ |YIN YANG
|RICARDO JIMENEZ  |In Neh Kwan
```

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es ordenarlos aleatoriamente hasta que se cumpla la condición que pides, si es que llegara a ser posible porque, si todos comparten academia, no se podría. Aunque, lo que más me intriga, es, ¿para qué querrías conseguir algo así? Lo habitual es que aparezcan ordenador para formar grupos, ¿no?

Comment: Sii pero cómo la consulta es para generar los brackets (llaves de competencia) para un torneo entonces las personas que les toca juntas no pueden ser de la misma categoría en lo más posible

Comment: Ah, entonces puedes numerarlos, empezando desde cero en cada academia y emparejarlos así con un `JOIN`... Inténtalo y, si no te sale, más tarde te respondo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución a partir de un dataset simplificado en el que me he quedado con los campos necesarios para ilustrar la propuesta:

```
CREATE TABLE atleta(
  nombre_at varchar(63),
  nom_academia_at varchar(63)
  );
INSERT INTO atleta (nombre_at, nom_academia_at) VALUES
('IVAN COTO','IN NEH KWAN'),
('RICARDO JIMENEZ','IN NEH KWAN'),
('THIAGO FERNANDEZ','YIN YANG'),
('SEBASTIAN ALVARADO SANABRIA','YIN YANG'),
('OTRO MÁS DE EJEMPLO','YIN YANG'),
('Y OTRO MÁS PARA QUE SEAN PARES','YIN PLUS');
```

En primer lugar, añade estos campos a tu tabla `atleta`:

```
ALTER TABLE atleta 
  ADD turno int,
  ADD id_atleta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Después, ejecuta esta consulta de actualización de datos para definir los turnos:

```
set @i:=0;
UPDATE atleta a JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      IF(@i>=(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atleta
      )/2,@i:=0,NULL) corte,
      @i:=@i+1 orden 
      FROM atleta
      ORDER BY nom_academia_at  
  ) c1 USING(id_atleta)
  set a.turno=orden;
```

Se ha optado por la estrategia de ordenar por academias y dividir la tabla en dos mitades, asignando al primero de la primera mitad con el primero de la segunda, y así sucesivamente. De esta forma se dificultan las coincidencias por academias/categorías.

Finalmente, el listado en el orden que necesitas:

```
SELECT * FROM atleta
  ORDER BY turno,nom_academia_at;
```

Para obtener:

```
+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| nombre_at                       | nom_academia_at | turno | id_atleta |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| IVAN COTO                       | IN NEH KWAN     |     1 |         1 |
| THIAGO FERNANDEZ                | YIN YANG        |     1 |         3 |
| RICARDO JIMENEZ                 | IN NEH KWAN     |     2 |         2 |
| SEBASTIAN ALVARADO SANABRIA     | YIN YANG        |     2 |         4 |
| Y OTRO MÁS PARA QUE SEAN PARES  | YIN PLUS        |     3 |         6 |
| OTRO MÁS DE EJEMPLO             | YIN YANG        |     3 |         5 |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
```

O, incluso por parejas:

```
SELECT a1.nombre_at,a1.nom_academia_at,
  a1.turno,
  a2.nombre_at,a2.nom_academia_at
  FROM atleta a1
  JOIN atleta a2 
  ON a1.turno=a2.turno
  AND a1.id_atleta<a2.id_atleta
  ORDER BY a1.turno;
```

Quedando así:

```
+----------------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| nombre_at            | nom_academia_at | turno | nombre_at                       | nom_academia_at |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| IVAN COTO            | IN NEH KWAN     |     1 | THIAGO FERNANDEZ                | YIN YANG        |
| RICARDO JIMENEZ      | IN NEH KWAN     |     2 | SEBASTIAN ALVARADO SANABRIA     | YIN YANG        |
| OTRO MÁS DE EJEMPLO  | YIN YANG        |     3 | Y OTRO MÁS PARA QUE SEAN PARES  | YIN PLUS        |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado muy bien